# If not login then redirect to Login with AuthorizeWebForm attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, attributes, forms-authentication

I have a controller with [AuthorizeWebForm] attribute.

Now, If I am not login and I want to access that page, then it gives me

> HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized. 
>   You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Now, How can I Handle that with using [AuthorizeWebForm] attribute? If I am not logged-in and try to access that page, then it should redirect to Login page.

Comment: Can we have your web.config section "authentication" and if you need access page without identification use location section

Comment: What is your `[AuthorizeWebForm]` attribute? And is this web forms or asp.net.mvc?

Comment: This is asp.net MVC Question

Comment: web.config code.<system.web>
    <sessionState timeout="480"></sessionState>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="52428800"  requestLengthDiskThreshold="2147483647"  />
    <!--executionTimeout and maxRequestLength is used for allowed upload larger file-->
    <customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Error/Index" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Error/Index" />
    </customErrors>
  </system.web>

Comment: Show the code for `[AuthorizeWebForm]` attribute or try replacing it with `[Authorize]` attribute.

Comment: I got the answer. please check my below answer and accept solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got solution. I just put below code to my web.config. the session was already checked in custom error class. if session is null, then it is redirecting to login page.

```
<authentication mode="Forms"> 
    <forms name=".SomeLoginCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880"     protection="All" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" /> 
</authentication>
```